# React-Native @react-navigation/stack from App.js ERROR

Tags: reactjs, react-native, yarnpkg, watchman

I have a problem with react-native. I am coding with VS Code on a Mac and always when I want to start my Project, I get this Error:

""
Unable to resolve module `@react-navigation/stack` from `App.js`: @react-navigation/stack could not be found within the project.

If you are sure the module exists, try these steps:

1. Clear watchman watches: watchman watch-del-all
2. Delete node_modules: rm -rf node_modules and run yarn install
3. Reset Metro's cache: yarn start --reset-cache
4. Remove the cache: rm -rf /tmp/metro-*

RCTFatal
__28-[RCTCxxBridge handleError:]_block_invoke
_dispatch_call_block_and_release
_dispatch_client_callout
_dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF
**CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE**
__CFRunLoopRun
CFRunLoopRunSpecific
GSEventRunModal
-[UIApplication _run]
UIApplicationMain
main
start
0x0
""

I have googled so much for solutions for this but couldn't find any.

Comment: Did you try pod-install?

Comment: Yes. In the ios folder. cd ios and then pod-install.